# ArrayList print repeated element

Tags: java, arraylist

```
sectionTreatment.setSurgeryPerformedGrid(Lists.newArrayList());


//testing
if (elementNodeExist(element, "surgery-performed-grid")) {
    NodeList childList = element.getElementsByTagName("surgery-performed-grid");

for(int i = 0; i < childList.getLength(); i++) {
    OromaxSurgeryPerformedGrid surgeryPerformedGrid1 = new OromaxSurgeryPerformedGrid();
    LOG.debug("childList.........." + childList);
    surgeryPerformedGrid1.setSurgeryPerformedDate(getStringValForElementTag(element, "surgery-performed-date"));
    surgeryPerformedGrid1.setSurgeryPerformedProcedureSpecify(getStringValForElementTag(element, "surgery-performed-procedure-specify"));
    surgeryPerformedGrid1.setSurgeryPerformedProcedureCode(new ArrayList<>());
    String surgeryPerformedCode = lookupMapperHelperService.getSurgeryPerformedCodeById(getIntValForElementTag(element, "surgery-performed-procedure"));
    if(surgeryPerformedCode != null && Pris3BMdmMapper.getSurgeryPerformedA(surgeryPerformedCode) != null) {
        surgeryPerformedGrid1.getSurgeryPerformedProcedureCode().add( Pris3BMdmMapper.getSurgeryPerformedA(surgeryPerformedCode));
    }
    String surgeryPerformedlv1 =lookupMapperHelperService.getSurgeryPerformedCodeById(getIntValForElementTag(element, "surgery-performed-procedure-detail-lvl1"));
    if(surgeryPerformedlv1 != null && Pris3BMdmMapper.getSurgeryPerformedA(surgeryPerformedlv1) != null) {
        surgeryPerformedGrid1.getSurgeryPerformedProcedureCode().add(Pris3BMdmMapper.getSurgeryPerformedA(surgeryPerformedlv1));
    }
    String surgeryPerformedlv2 = lookupMapperHelperService.getSurgeryPerformedCodeById(getIntValForElementTag(element, "surgery-performed-procedure-detail-lvl2"));
    if(surgeryPerformedlv2 != null && Pris3BMdmMapper.getSurgeryPerformedA(surgeryPerformedlv2) != null) {
        surgeryPerformedGrid1.getSurgeryPerformedProcedureCode().add(Pris3BMdmMapper.getSurgeryPerformedA(surgeryPerformedlv2));
    }
    surgeryPerformedGrid1.setSurgeryPerformedType(Pris3BMdmMapper.getSurgeryPerformedA(String.valueOf(lookupMapperHelperService.getOromaxLevelCodeById(getIntValForElementTag(element, "surgery-performed-type")))));
    surgeryPerformedGrid1.setSurgeryPerformedSite(lookupMapperHelperService.getOromaxProcedureSiteCodeById(getIntValForElementTag(element, "surgery-performed-site")));
    surgeryPerformedGrid1.setSurgeryPerformedLaterality(lookupMapperHelperService.getLateralityCodeById(getIntValForElementTag(element, "surgery-performed-laterality")));
    surgeryPerformedGrid1.setSurgeryPerformedSiteOthers(getStringValForElementTag(element, "surgery-performed-site-others"));

    sectionTreatment.getSurgeryPerformedGrid().add(surgeryPerformedGrid1);
}
```

My code supposedly read and print the element inside tag "surgery-performed-grid" in xml. But the my output keep print the first element of the tag. my output :

```
"surgeryPerformedGrid": [{
            "surgeryPerformedDate": "2018-09-11",
            "surgeryPerformedProcedureCode": ["01"],
            "surgeryPerformedSite": "02",
            "surgeryPerformedSiteOthers": null,
            "surgeryPerformedLaterality": null,
            "surgeryPerformedType": null,
            "surgeryPerformedProcedureSpecify": null
        }, {
            "surgeryPerformedDate": "2018-09-11",
            "surgeryPerformedProcedureCode": ["01"],
            "surgeryPerformedSite": "02",
            "surgeryPerformedSiteOthers": null,
            "surgeryPerformedLaterality": null,
            "surgeryPerformedType": null,
            "surgeryPerformedProcedureSpecify": null
```

This code keep add same object(surgeryPerformedGrid1) in ArrayList. How to add different object(each element) in ArrayList?

```
 sectionTreatment.getSurgeryPerformedGrid().add(surgeryPerformedGrid1);
```

Thank you.

Comment: you never use `childList`. In every iteration you use the same `element` instance.

Comment: You are in a foor lop but I fail to see where you use the current childList element...

Comment: I have already debug using LOG.debug(); my iterator seems dont have a problem. the problem is when sectionTreatment.getSurgeryPerformedGrid().add(surgeryPerformedGrid1); this code add same object

Comment: what iterator? you always generate a new object with the same content and add that to the list.

Comment: You are passing all the childList every time to the log. It will print the same in every loop. **But** you aren't using the `i` variable inside the for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parent element in for, so you code should be something like this:

```
sectionTreatment.setSurgeryPerformedGrid(Lists.newArrayList());


//testing
if (elementNodeExist(element, "surgery-performed-grid")) {
    NodeList childList = element.getElementsByTagName("surgery-performed-grid");

for(currentElement: childList) {
        OromaxSurgeryPerformedGrid surgeryPerformedGrid1 = new OromaxSurgeryPerformedGrid();
    LOG.debug("childList.........." + childList);
    surgeryPerformedGrid1.setSurgeryPerformedDate(getStringValForcurrentElementTag(currentElement, "surgery-performed-date"));
    surgeryPerformedGrid1.setSurgeryPerformedProcedureSpecify(getStringValForcurrentElementTag(currentElement, "surgery-performed-procedure-specify"));
    surgeryPerformedGrid1.setSurgeryPerformedProcedureCode(new ArrayList<>());
    String surgeryPerformedCode = lookupMapperHelperService.getSurgeryPerformedCodeById(getIntValForcurrentElementTag(currentElement, "surgery-performed-procedure"));
    if(surgeryPerformedCode != null && Pris3BMdmMapper.getSurgeryPerformedA(surgeryPerformedCode) != null) {
        surgeryPerformedGrid1.getSurgeryPerformedProcedureCode().add( Pris3BMdmMapper.getSurgeryPerformedA(surgeryPerformedCode));
    }
    String surgeryPerformedlv1 =lookupMapperHelperService.getSurgeryPerformedCodeById(getIntValForcurrentElementTag(currentElement, "surgery-performed-procedure-detail-lvl1"));
    if(surgeryPerformedlv1 != null && Pris3BMdmMapper.getSurgeryPerformedA(surgeryPerformedlv1) != null) {
        surgeryPerformedGrid1.getSurgeryPerformedProcedureCode().add(Pris3BMdmMapper.getSurgeryPerformedA(surgeryPerformedlv1));
    }
    String surgeryPerformedlv2 = lookupMapperHelperService.getSurgeryPerformedCodeById(getIntValForcurrentElementTag(currentElement, "surgery-performed-procedure-detail-lvl2"));
    if(surgeryPerformedlv2 != null && Pris3BMdmMapper.getSurgeryPerformedA(surgeryPerformedlv2) != null) {
        surgeryPerformedGrid1.getSurgeryPerformedProcedureCode().add(Pris3BMdmMapper.getSurgeryPerformedA(surgeryPerformedlv2));
    }
    surgeryPerformedGrid1.setSurgeryPerformedType(Pris3BMdmMapper.getSurgeryPerformedA(String.valueOf(lookupMapperHelperService.getOromaxLevelCodeById(getIntValForcurrentElementTag(currentElement, "surgery-performed-type")))));
    surgeryPerformedGrid1.setSurgeryPerformedSite(lookupMapperHelperService.getOromaxProcedureSiteCodeById(getIntValForcurrentElementTag(currentElement, "surgery-performed-site")));
    surgeryPerformedGrid1.setSurgeryPerformedLaterality(lookupMapperHelperService.getLateralityCodeById(getIntValForcurrentElementTag(currentElement, "surgery-performed-laterality")));
    surgeryPerformedGrid1.setSurgeryPerformedSiteOthers(getStringValForcurrentElementTag(currentElement, "surgery-performed-site-others"));

    sectionTreatment.getSurgeryPerformedGrid().add(surgeryPerformedGrid1);
}
```